# how to take multiple chracter in argv in python

Tags: python, argv

i am new in python3 and currently learning it i have written small code below. i want to know that why argv is taking single character only? for every variable. isn't it supposed to take whole string(multiple characters)? in other words when i input in console it only hold four single characters. every variable have just one character.

```
from sys import argv

def main(argv): 

    script, first, second, third = argv
    print ("The script is called:", script)
    print ("Your first variable is:", first)
    print ("Your second variable is:", second)
    print ("Your third variable is:", third)

main(input())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get arguments from the command line, `main` doesn't need a parameter, and you don't need to call `input`. You're merely overwriting `sys.argv` when you do that.

```
from sys import argv

def main(): 

    script, first, second, third = argv
    print ("The script is called:", script)
    print ("Your first variable is:", first)
    print ("Your second variable is:", second)
    print ("Your third variable is:", third)

main()
```

Result:

```
C:\Users\kevin\programs>py -3 test.py hurf durf klurf
The script is called: test.py
Your first variable is: hurf
Your second variable is: durf
Your third variable is: klurf
```

---

Alternatively, if you really *do* want to get information from `input`, and you just got confused reading about argv, then you can use `split` to get words from the input string rather than letters. Of course, you can't get the script's name this way.

```
def main(data): 

    script, first, second, third = data.split()
    print ("The script is called:", script)
    print ("Your first variable is:", first)
    print ("Your second variable is:", second)
    print ("Your third variable is:", third)

main(input("Enter some data: "))
```

Result:

```
Enter some data: hello how are you?
The script is called: hello
Your first variable is: how
Your second variable is: are
Your third variable is: you?
```

Comment: instead of running this program from cmd if i want to run this program in eclipse how would i run that? as i couldn't figure out how to read python.py files

Comment: If you couldn't figure out how to get eclipse to work with python files, how were you running this script before?

Comment: i was running by taking input() in console but when i type in console it doesn't take more then four single character but when same thing i run in cmd it take full string multiple character so i was confused that why in eclipse its not working

Comment: @KhurramHameed Your new questionisn't really related to this question or answer.  Could you please ask it as a new question?  That way others have a chance to help.